# How can I move a Netbeans project to a different folder?

Tags: netbeans

I've accidentally created a few NetBeans projects outside of my Dropbox folder, and I want to move the projects to the correct folder. Is there any way to change a project's directory using the NetBeans user interface?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Right-click on the project you want to move in the "projects" tab, and then click "move". This will allow you to move the project to a new directory.

Comment: This procedure doesn't seem to be reliable. I had broken projects after using the function. (NetBeans 8.0.2 on Windows 8.1)

Comment: This method will work but you'll lose the file history you had beyond the history from your git commits. Does anyone know how to carry over the history?